# Calculate the residues of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Calculate the residues of this complex function

$$\frac{1}{z^2\sin(z)}$$

I can notice that we have singularities at $z=n\pi$, where $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$
But, how to find the residues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate by cases:

$$z=0\;\implies\;\frac1{z^2\sin z}=\frac1{z^2\left(z-\frac{z^3}6+\ldots\right)}=\frac1{z^3\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+
\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=\frac1{z^3}\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\frac{z^4}{36}+\ldots\right)=...+\frac1{6z}+\ldots$$

Thus, $\;z=0\;$ is a pole of order three and the function's residue at it is $\;\frac16\;$ .

$$z=n\pi,\,n\in\Bbb Z\;\implies\;\text{the poles are the same as those of sine and thus are simple, so:}$$

$$\text{Res}_{z=n\pi}(fg)=\lim_{z\to n\pi}\frac{z-n\pi}{z^2\sin z}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{z\to n\pi}\frac1{2z\sin z+z^2\cos z}=\frac1{n^2\pi^2(-1)^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2\pi^2}$$

Comment: I got lost at the second math line. Are you saing that $\frac{1}{a+b+c+d+\dots}=a+b+c+d+\dots$?

Comment: @AlejandroJiménezRico Of course not. I am using the geometric series expansion. Since we're interested in $\;z\;$ close to zero, we can then assume that $\;\left|\frac{z^2}6-\frac{z^4}{120}+\ldots\right|<1\;$ , and then $$\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}6+\ldots}=1+\frac{z^2}6+\ldots$$, just like $$\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\ldots\;,\;\;|z|<1$$

Comment: I think I got it. You said that $(1 + z^2/6 + \dots)$ is almost $1$, so it's pretty much the same multiplying it or dividing it. Right?

Comment: @AlejandroJiménezRico No, I didn't say that. I meant exactly what I wrote. You must know this as it is part of power series, which it is usually covered in real analysis before complex analysis.

Comment: I have revisited this and know it is pretty clear. Maybe I would suggest a tiny  edition pointing out the geometric series expansion.

Comment: @DonAntonio Is l'Hopital's rule applicable to functions from C to C?

Comment: The series for $\frac{z}{\sin(z)}=1+\frac{z^2}6+\frac{7z^4}{360}+O\!\left(z^6\right)$

Comment: @AA Yes, it is in the appropiate cases.