# Can l'Hopital's rule be used to compute residues? If so, when and when not?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've read this on math stack exchange:

[Calculate the residues of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2\sin z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836115/calculate-the-residues-of-fz-frac1z2-sin-z)

The person who is answering the question about residues applies l'Hopital's rule to a quotient of functions from C to C. Is this allowed? Wikipedia seems to indicate that the rule mentioned is applicable only to quotients of functions from R to R.

Important is maybe that the question concerns residues at points on the real line. If a limit exists regardless of the direction by which we approach a real point, then that limit is probably equal to the limit of the quotient if we approach the point only along the real line. Am I right about this, and can that justify the use of l'Hopital's rule in a case where it is a first glance not applicable?

Whether l'Hopital's rule is or isn't applicable to complex functions has been asked on math stack exchange before. A couple of persons who address that question seem inclined to answer it affirmatively, but no one says yes with a firm voice, thereby contradicting Wikipedia. If Wikipedia is wrong, that is if we are in fact allowed to apply the rule to complex functions, what are the exact conditions under which we may do that? That's what I would like to know.