# Should I trust Wikipedia or Mathematics stack exchange concerning l'Hopital's rule?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, definition

According to Wikipedia, l'Hopital's rule is applicable only to functions from R to R, but some authors on Mathematics stack exchange seem to claim that it's applicable also to functions from C to C. What should I believe? Which source is more reliable?

[Calculate the residues of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2\sin z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836115/calculate-the-residues-of-fz-frac1z2-sin-z)

[Is L'Hopitals rule applicable to complex functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions)

Comment: Where does Wikipedia state that l'Hopital's rule is applicable only to functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: You have to be very careful with complex numbers. Many properties transform , but not all.

Comment: I don't see anywhere on the second link that indicates LR cannot be used on complex functions.

Comment: "L'Hôpital's rule" is an umbrella term for various theorems providing sufficient conditions for $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ (or, for $a\in\Bbb R$, $\lim_{x\to a^\pm}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a^\pm}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$). [_Wikipedia_'s article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hopital%27s_rule) mentions examples involving real and extended real numbers, and _happens_ not to discuss complex cases, but you only need work through "real" proofs to see how easily they generalize (although sometimes the limits only exist in suitable directions).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos When Wikipedia mentions the conditions for l'Hopital's rule to be valid, it states that the functions involved should be functions from R to R, so it implicitely excludes functions from C to C.

Comment: You are assuming there is only one possible result with the name "l'Hopital's rule."

Comment: Please note that the article contains a section concerning [cases where the theorem cannot be applied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Cases_where_theorem_cannot_be_applied_(Necessity_of_conditions)) and that even there no mention is made of complex numbers.

Comment: @Randall Both links are to math stack exchange. I don't have a link to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @J.G. If a limit sometimes exists only in a suitable direction, doesn't that mean precisely that l'Hopital's rule is not applicable to complex functions in general?

Comment: What I mean is some such "rules" are about limits, while some are about directional limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex versions of l'Hôpital's Rule can be found in many Complex Analysis texts, e.g. [Levinson and Redheffer](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Complex_Variables/x5knAQAAIAAJ) Example 7.1:

Let $f$ and $g$ be analytic in a domain $D$ and not identically $0$.  If $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha) = 0$ at a point $\alpha$ of $D$, show that

$$ \lim_{z \to \alpha} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \lim_{z \to \alpha} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}, $$ the value $\infty$ being allowed in both cases.